# Can't create two different new Account objects in Salesforce test

Tags: unit-test

I'm getting some strange behavior when I'm setting up some data for my test. I'm creating two account objects, but when I add a checkpoint and look at the account objects, they have the same data.

My account setup inside the test does this:

```
Account account1 = createAccount();
account1.Name = 'Account 1';
insert account1;

Account account2 = createAccount();
account2.Name = 'Account 2';
insert account2;
```

My method that creates an account looks like this:

```
static Account createAccount() {
  Account account = new Account();
  account.Name = 'New account';
  account.BillingStreet = 'street';

  return account;
}
```

The checkpoint looks like this after the test runs. Notice the id and name are the same for both variables:
[image: both objects have the same id and name]

I have put in some more checkpoints and the two objects start having the same values as soon as I create the second account. It doesn't make a difference whether I insert account1 before I create account2 or not.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could try adding the following assert in multiple places to see where the `account1` reference ends up pointing at `account2`. Assert Statement: `System.assertEquals('Account 1', [select Name from Account where Id = :account1.Id].Name);`

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue using your code. Is there any other code that you have left out that may be important? ie a static variable for Account?

Comment: Thanks @BarCotter, putting together a simple sample helped me figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with simpler version of your code and it appears as bug in developer console.

```
public class try1{
public try1(){
    Account account1 = new Account();
    account1.Name = 'Account 1';    

    Account account3 =  new Account();
    account3.Name = 'Account 3';   

    System.debug('##' + account1.Name);
    System.debug('##' + account3.Name);
}
```

}

When i check with checkpoints on line 10 & 11 it shows both account names as Account 3.

Comment: It seems to be only an issue with checkpoints. When I use a system.debug() command, I get the right Id and Name for each object.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with the [checkpoint](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&language=en_US) rather than your code. I added the test below. The assertNotEquals line in the code is passing, meaning that the `account1` and `account2` have different id values.

```
@isTest
private class SimpleTest {

    @isTest
    static void test() {
        Account account1 = createAccount();
        account1.Name = 'Account 1';
        insert account1;

        Account account2 = createAccount();
        account2.Name = 'Account 2';
        insert account2;

        System.assertNotEquals(account1.Id, account2.Id);
        System.debug('Account1: ' + account1.Id + ' Account2: ' + account2.Id);
    }

    private static Account createAccount() {
      Account account = new Account();
      account.Name = 'New account';
      account.BillingStreet = 'street';

      return account;
    }
}
```

But when I add a [checkpoint](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&language=en_US) to the last line it is showing that both accounts hold a reference to `account1`, see screenshot below.

The debug statement is printed out is `Account1: 0015000000t4jQFAAY Account2: 0015000000t4jQGAAY`, which verifies that the code is correct.

[image]

The next steps for you on this would be to create a case with SalesForce to let them know that the checkpoints are not working correctly.

Comment: I'll do that. Thankyou for your help, but I'd already marked the other answer as correct before I saw yours.

Comment: No problem @Helephant.